# Jquery Form Field Focus Change Submit Button Class

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I have the following form:

```
<input name="q" value="" class="qa-search-field">
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="qa-search-button">
```

I am trying to get the submit button's class to change when the qa-search-field is active by adding the class .qa-search-button-active, and then removing it if the search form is not active,  meaning the cursor is not on there and blinking.

Cant figure out how to code this in Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".qa-search-field").focusin(function() {
   $('.qa-search-button').addClass('.qa-search-button-active');
});

(".qa-search-field").focusout(function() {
   $('.qa-search-button').removeClass('.qa-search-button-active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('input[name="q"]').focus(function(event){
        $('input[type="submit"]).attr('class', 'qa-search-button-active');
    });


    $('input[name="q"]').focus(function(event){
        $('input[type="submit"]).attr('class', 'qa-search-button');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this late solution ? :)

```
$(".qa-search-field").focus(function () {
    $('.qa-search-button').removeClass('qa-search-button').addClass('qa-search-button-active');
});

$(".qa-search-field").blur(function () {
    $('.qa-search-button-active').removeClass('qa-search-button-active').addClass('qa-search-button');
});
```